# Linear Combination of Counters in Python

Tags: python, counter

I have some Counter objects like below representing the left hand side and right hand side of an equation:

Left Hand Side: `(Counter({22.99: 1}), Counter({12.011: 2, 15.999: 2}), Counter({12.011: 7}))`

Right Hand Side: `Counter({12.011: 15, 15.999: 1})`

My objective is to find the common elements between both sides of the equation and then determine a linear combination of the left that can give me the right side.

In the example above, the equation to solve would be:

```
2A*12.011 + 7B*12.011 = 15W*12.011

2A*15.999 = W*15.999
```

I anticipate this operation would involve converting the Counter dictionary to a matrix to solve a system of linear equations but am stuck on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution very much along the lines of your approach.

1. Convert each Counter to a vector, treating different IDs as separate dimensions.
2. Solve a system of linear equations.

---

```
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg


lhs = (Counter({22.99: 1}), Counter({12.011: 2, 15.999: 2}), Counter({12.011: 7}))
rhs = Counter({12.011: 15, 15.999: 1})

# get unique keys that occur in any Counter in 2D
# each unique key represents a separate dimension
ks = np.array([*set().union(rhs, *lhs)])[:, None]

# get a helper function to convert Counters to vectors
ctr_to_vec = np.vectorize(Counter.__getitem__)

lhs_mat = ctr_to_vec(lhs, ks)
rhs_vec = ctr_to_vec(rhs, ks)

# compute coefficients solving the least-squares problem
coefs = linalg.lstsq(lhs_mat, rhs_vec)[0]

is_linear_comb = np.allclose(lhs_mat @ coefs, rhs_vec)
```

Comment: The default iterator for Counters produces keys. There is no need to call keys on them so rather than `[*set().union(rhs.keys()).union(*(lh.keys() for lh in lhs))]` one can write `[*set().union(rhs, *lhs)]`

Comment: Ah, that's so much nicer. Thanks!

Comment: I found the definition of ks and is_linear_comb gave me a syntax error. The error went away with the following commands:

Comment: 1. ks = np.array(list(set().union(rhs, *lhs)))[:, None]

Comment: @user2657817 are you using Python2? If so, you should replace `lhs_mat @ coefs` with `np.dot(lhs_mat, coefs)`.

Comment: 2. is_linear_comb = np.allclose(np.matmul(lhs_mat,coefs), rhs_vec)

Comment: Are there any other errors? I tested everything on Python 3.6 with numpy 1.14.5.

Comment: If I wanted the co-efficients to be positive and whole numbers, how would I improve your solution to do that.

Comment: If you suspect that a linear combination with whole numbers exists, you could try clearing the denominators in a fractional solution. After you have guessed a combination with integer coefficients, you can verify it exactly. There are packages like `sagemath` that support linear algebra over rationals, but whether that is useful depends on your application.

Comment: For positive coefficients, you could try something along the lines of `sp.optimize.minimize` with least squares as the objective and positivity constraints on the coefficients, though that will be less efficient than using `linalg`.

Comment: Actually, it may be useful to think of your lhs counters as spanning a lattice over Z. I bet there are some algorithms for testing if rhs is in such a lattice, but I do not know the reference. Also this is probably NP hard.

Comment: I ended up using sp.optimize.nnls for getting non-negative co-efficients. If I get a vector like [0.377, 0.5, 0], I need to multiply the co-efficients so that it corresponds to a linearly dependent/scaled vector with whole numbers.

Comment: I take my advice back. This is an integer programming problem, and I doubt that we can invent a solution that beats standard [tools](https://pythonhosted.org/PuLP/). If you know more about the structure of the counters, there may be a better specialized algorithm.

Comment: Part of the problem is that there may be a continuum of solutions if lhs contains linearly independent vectors, and going back to an integral solution from a numeric one sounds hard.